Phantom points in QGIS do not dissapear
Does anybody know how to delete these red dots with tooltips?
There are not connected to any layer. Even if i delete all layers from the project these points remane in an empty project.
Closing the project and reopen it, does not help. I don´t even know where they come from.
I´m using QGIS-LTR 3.34.7.


These are called "text annotations" and are part of the annotations introduced with QGIS 3.22: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/map_view.html#annotation-tools
Click on the text annotations symbol , then click on the annotations and hit the delete button on your keyboard.
If you do not see that button, you need to enable "Annotations Toolbar" via View --> Toolbars.
